# How much better are the higher levels of the ammo bonuses?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

There seem to be different levels of the different ammo powers you can apply as a bonus for one multiplayer round:

[image]

I just got the Incendiary Rounds II in a Veteran Pack I bought, and I'm wondering how much better the level 2 ammo powers are than their level 1 counterparts. As far as I can tell the type of pack you buy determines which level you get, depending on how much better the higher level powers are I might want to buy more Veteran or even Spectre packs.

Answer (score 2):

They will increase panic chance by 15%.

" Rank 1

Shoot and your enemy will burst into flames.

More weapon damage. Weaken armor. Chance to make an enemy panic.

rank 2

Improve the odds of panicking a target by 15%.

rank 3

Increase health and armor damage bonuses by 4%.

rank 4

Damage OR Squad Bonus Increase health and damage bonuses by 6%. Squadmates gain Incendiary Ammo at 50% effectiveness.

rank 5

Ammo Capacity OR Headshots Increase ammo capacity by 30%. Increase headshot damage by 25%.

Rank 6

Damage OR Explosive Burst Increase health and armor damage bonuses by 10%. Ignite enemies with an intermittent explosion that covers 2.50 meters for 100"

Sources: Mass Effect Wiki, IGN.com.

Comment: Those are the singleplayer stats, do you have any source that the multiplayer stats are the same? The multiplayer ranks also only go to rank 3, as far as I have observerd so far.

Comment: From what I gathered, it seemed like they would be the same, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1):

It increases the panic chance a bit.